# Http request using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, http, request

I have to send some command using HTTP request to some applications that have embedded http server.I'm using sockets,so far I did this but I'm a little lost:

```
 URI uri = URI.create(rawData);
    try {

        String host = uri.getHost();
        String path = uri.getRawPath( );
        if (path == null || path.length( ) == 0) {
            path = "/";
        }
        String protocol = uri.getScheme( );
        int port = uri.getPort( );
        if (port == -1) {
            if (protocol.equals("http")) {
                port = 80; // http port
            }
            else if (protocol.equals("https")) {
                port = 443; // https port
            }
        }
        Socket socket = new Socket( host, port );
        PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream() );
        request.print(  "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                   "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        request.flush( );
```

Is this all I need to do?
An example of rawData is `"http://somemessage"`.Is the protocol written correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have special reasons not to use `URLConnection`?

Comment: @AlexR Not really,the only thing I should take into consideration is to do this without opening a browser tab,as till now it this was made this way: "Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(rawData));"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this all I need to do?

Nope.

1. You need to process the response, and there is complexity in dealing with the various kinds of responses you could receive.
2. The way you are handling HTTPS is all wrong.  You need to deal with SSL connection negotiation ... and if you try to do that using plain sockets you have a huge amount of coding to do.

> An example of rawData is `"http://somemessage"`

What is a strange URL.  The stuff after the "//" should be (or include) a resolvable hostname or IP address.  If you tried to fetch a URL like that using a web browser, it would not work.

> Is the protocol written correctly?

Certainly the URL is not written correctly.  If you try to use that so-called URL with `HttpURLConnection`, or any the other client-side HTTP API (see below), **IT WILL NOT WORK**!!!

A typical well-formed URL (in this case, with an explicit port number) looks like this:

```
    http://example.com:8080/path/to/resource
```

You can also express URIs in relative form; e.g.

```
    http:/path/to/resource
```

or

```
    http:relpath/to/resource
```

or even

```
    resource
```

but those two forms need to be turned into absolute (URL) form before they can be used by a client library.

---

But frankly, this is the wrong way to go about things.  There are existing implementations of the client-side HTTP / HTTPS stack in the Java SE libraries, and also in the Apache HTTP libraries.  Attempting to reimplement them is a waste of time.

Comment: I know it won't work,that was the main propose of my task to send the message without using the browser,just to do that as a background task,the message represents some commands for the external tools,that they should execute.

Comment: @TudorR - If you know it won't work, why are you even trying to do it?  And what makes you think you can't use (say) `HttpUrlConnection` to send requests in the background?  Sorry, but your comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: At the moment a URL like http:// 5195+JT+Equity5195JT is processed using Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(url)),in my app but for this each time I send a request it opens a empty tab in my browser,and I have to make it work without opening it as it is useless the http protocol is used only to share the message between my app and some other external ones.I'm using fiddler to check if it was sent.It's a very large project and I'm new to it,so I don't have   a clear idea on this,but as I see it's used just for sharing info.I'm a little confused too.

Comment: So **why** are you using `Desktop.getDesktop().browse` rather than `HttpUrlConnection`?  It is entirely expected behaviour for `browse` to open a browser window.  If you read the javadoc, you will see that that is the *primary purpose* of that call!!

Comment: I should also point out that `"http:// 5195+JT+Equity5195JT"` is not a valid URL.  As I said above, the stuff after the `"//"` ... up to the next `"/"` should be (or include) a valid hostname or IP address.  What you have shown us above is patently invalid.

Comment: You got the idea wrong from the beginning,I certainly know what is the purpose of Desktop.getDesktop().browse,but my task was to get rid of it and make it "browserless".

Comment: Yeah you are right ,I'm new to this app and I had no idea how to configure the host and port.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use higher-level JDK APIs instead of the lower-level **Socket** API for your requirement. Please refer to the following links -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Below is a sample snippet with **HttpURLConnection** API -

```
String urlString = "http://myhost/mywebapp/myresource";
URL url= new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.getResponseCode();
```